Recommender system with Keras using matrix factorization
I am trying to build a model for movie recommendation using Keras.
I am using matrix factorization and everything is working except for the last, and most important, part where I use the model to recommend something.
I have the following:
from keras import regularizers
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

def get_mf_bias_l2_reg_model(nb_users, nb_movies, k, lambda_):
    """
    Build a smatrix factorization model with user and movie biases, and L2 regularization

    Input:
        nb_users : int : The number of unique users
        nb_movies : int : The number of unique movies
        k : int : The size of the embeddings
    
    Output:
        model : keras.models.Model : A keras model that implements matrix factorization with biases and L2 regularization
    
    """

    dim_embedddings = k

    # Regularizers
    u_reg = regularizers.l2(lambda_)
    i_reg = regularizers.l2(lambda_)

    # User embeddings
    u = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int32', name='u__user_id')
    p_u = Embedding(nb_users, dim_embedddings, embeddings_regularizer=u_reg, name="p_u__user_embedding")(u)
    p_u = Reshape((dim_embedddings,), name="p_u__user_embedding_reshaped")(p_u)

    # Movie embeddings
    i = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int32', name = 'i__movie_id')
    q_i = Embedding(nb_movies, dim_embedddings, embeddings_regularizer=i_reg, name="q_i__movie_embedding")(i)
    q_i = Reshape((dim_embedddings,), name="q_i__movie_embedding_reshaped")(q_i)
    
    # Dot product
    d = Dot(axes = 1)([p_u, q_i])

    # Bias
    b_u = Embedding(nb_users, 1, embeddings_regularizer=u_reg, name="user_bias_embedding")(u)
    b_u = Reshape((1,), name="user_bias_embedding_reshaped")(b_u)
    b_i = Embedding(nb_movies, 1, embeddings_regularizer=i_reg, name="item_bias_embedding")(i)
    b_i = Reshape((1,), name="item_bias_embedding_reshaped")(b_i)

    r_hat = Add()([b_i + b_u + d])

    model = Model(inputs=[u, i], outputs=r_hat) 

    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=["mse"])

    return model

And a function for doing a gridsearch which I will not reproduce here to save space, but it is something like:
def grid_search(data, param_grid, get_model_function, nb_users, nb_movies,validation_size=0.1):
    """
    Performs a grid search 

    Input:
        data : DataFrame : The training set to be split between training and validation sets
        param_grid : dict : Dictionary containing the values of the hyper-parameters to grid-search
        get_model_function : function : A function that returns the keras model to grid-search
        nb_users : int : The number of unique users
        nb_movies : int : The number of unique movies
        validation_size : float : Proportion of the validation set
    
    Output:
        best_params : dict : A dictionary of the best hyper-parameters values
        best_score : float : The validation RMSE corresponding to the best
        best_model : keras.Model : The model trained with the best hyper-parameters
    
    """
 [...] code.......

    print(f"The best fitted model returned a score of {best_score:.4f} with hyper-parameters {best_params}")

    return best_params, best_score, best_model

Then I use it all:
lambdas_ = [0.0002, 0.00005, 0.00002]
ks = [15, 30]

param_grid = dict(k=ks, lambda_=lambdas_)

best_params, best_score, best_model = grid_search(train, param_grid, get_mf_bias_l2_reg_model, nb_users, nb_movies, validation_size=0.1)

And I want to make predictions:
y_pred = best_model.predict(X_test)
test_rmse = sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))

print("Best model test RMSE : %s " % test_rmse)

X = [rating_df["userId"].to_numpy(), rating_df["movieId"].to_numpy()]
y = rating_df["rating"].to_numpy()


best_model = get_mf_bias_l2_reg_model(nb_users, nb_movies, k=best_params["k"], lambda_=best_params["lambda_"])

early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_mse', patience=10, verbose=1, restore_best_weights=True)

model_fitted = best_model.fit(X, y, epochs=500, batch_size=512, validation_split=0.1, callbacks=[early_stopping])

Now I want to use it to recommend movies for 10 users, according to the task:

With your retrained best model with optimal hyper parameters, compute the predictions for all the ratings that are not in the dataset for the 10 first users (indexes from 0 to 9). That means all the movies i that these users u ∈ 0,...,9 haven't rated, thus all the u,i combinations that are not in the dataset dataframe rows.
Order these predicted ratings for these users by decreasing order, and print out the 5 first ones, i.e. the ones that have the highest predicted ratings. Use the movies.csv file to print the real titles.

I tried the following:
def get_top5_for_user(model, user_id, dataset):
    """
    Returns a list of the 5 movies that have the highest ratings among the unrated moviesrating_df of user `user_id`, along with a list of their predicted ratings.

    Input :
        model : keras.models.Model : A trained matrix factorization model
        user_id : int : The user id to use
        dataset : DataFrame : The whole dataset, useful to find the movies the user `user_id` has already rated

    Output :
        five_best_movie_ids : list : The five movie ids among unrated movies by user `user_id` that have the highest predicted ratings, in order
        five_best_ratings : list : The corresponding five ratings
    """

    test = test.loc[dataset["userId"] == user_id]

    predictions = model.predict([test.userId, test.movieId])

    return five_best_movie_ids, five_best_ratings

The function above is not completed yet. Before filling it, I tried some data to see if I could make the predictions and the recommendations:
user_id = 0

user_ratings = rating_df[rating_df["userId"] == user_id][["userId", "movieId", "rating"]]
user_ratings["prediction"] = best_model.predict([user_ratings["userId"], user_ratings["movieId"]])
user_ratings.sort_values(by="rating", 
                         ascending=False).merge(movies_df, 
                                                on="movieId", 
                                                how="inner", 
                                                suffixes=["_u", "_m"])

The output is:
userId  movieId rating  prediction  title   genres
0   0   186 5.0 3.298577    Gulliver's Travels (1939)   Adventure|Animation|Children
1   0   70  5.0 4.883185    Raiders of the Lost Ark (Indiana Jones and the...   Action|Adventure
2   0   102 5.0 3.678330    Conan the Barbarian (1982)  Action|Adventure|Fantasy
3   0   53  5.0 3.860772    Dumbo (1941)    Animation|Children|Drama|Musical
4   0   124 5.0 3.469780    Great Mouse Detective, The (1986)   Action|Animation|Children|Crime

... ... ... ... ... ... ...
But I don't know how to continue. What I tried for recommendations:
recommendations = rating_df[rating_df["movieId"].isin(user_ratings["movieId"]) == False [["movieId"]].drop_duplicates()
recommendations["prediction"] = best_model.predict([user_ratings["userId"], user_ratings["movieId"]])

But it gives an error:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[52], line 2
      1 recommendations = rating_df[rating_df["movieId"].isin(user_ratings["movieId"]) == False][["movieId"]].drop_duplicates()
----> 2 recommendations["prediction"] = best_model.predict([user_ratings["userId"], user_ratings["movieId"]])
  
ValueError: Length of values (232) does not match length of index (9492)

Which is expected, actually, since the length of user_ratings is 232 rows (the 232 movies that the specific user, i.e user_id = 0, I am considering has rated). While recommendations has 9492 rows corresponding to the 9492 movies that the user_id = 0 hasn't rated. But my model recquires the two entries X["userId"], X["movieId"] but I don't know what to put in X.
